# how to close or minimize or maximize app in react electron

Tags: reactjs, electron, electron-react

I'm building a react-electron app. I created a custom window header but I can't access app.quit() & a.*() in my project.

app.js(react):

```
i tried both type :
```

1.import electron from "electron";
2.const electron = require('electron')

```
<div onClick={()=>{
electron.app.quit()
}} </div>
```

main.js :

```
const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 900,
    height: 675,
    frame: false,
    webPreferences: {
        nodeIntegration: true,
        enableRemoteModule: true
    }

})
mainWindow.loadURL('http://localhost:3000');
```

i run the app with this script:

```
"start": "concurrently \"npm run react-start\" \"wait-on http://localhost:3000 && electron .\"",
```

i got this error :
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found the answer. hope this help someone :
add this to your main.js:

```
webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: true,
            enableRemoteModule: true,
            contextIsolation: false
        }
```

and use it in react component like this:

```
const { ipcRenderer } = window.require('electron');

<img onClick={()=>{ipcRenderer.send('close',[])}}  src={""}/>
```

and use it in main.js like this :

```
const {ipcMain} = require('electron')

ipcMain.on('close',()=>app.quit())
```

Comment: You should watch [here](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/context-isolation) the danger when disable contextIsolation.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use the ipc to send message from renderer(React) to main process (Nodejs). For exemple, if you want to close , you can listen the event in main process like this.

```
this.ipcMain.on('closeApp', () => {
      this.win.close();
    });
```

And send the event from renderer like this

```
window.electron.ipcRenderer.sendMessage('closeApp');
```